# Azure AD - Get Client Secret Description from Token

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

For my project I'll have multiple daemon apps making calls to my API with tokens obtained by Client Secret keys.  I need a way to identify which calls are coming from which clients, and I was thinking I could use the Description field that is set when adding a Client Secret Key in Azure AD administration.  However I've parsed the token's entire payload, and I don't see it in there.

Is there a way to obtain that description using the token?  OR is there another way to go about identifying different api users based on the secret key they're using?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot know which key was used.

You need to register them as different client apps in Azure AD to differentiate them.

Comment: Is there any way to have a daemon app log into AAD without an interface where I can know its identity?

Comment: Yes, the client credentials flow. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: The appid claim in the access token will identify the app

Comment: I might have several clients hitting the same application, I could give them different secret keys but they'd all be using the same app, so the appid isn't going to identify them from one another.

Comment: Yeah, so you need separate apps